# django translation ngettext not working with gettext in the same file

Tags: django, translation, gettext

this is my setup to generate translations for both singular and plurar text

```
from django.utils.translations import ngettext as _
from django.utils.translations import gettext

num = 3
my_plural_string = _("{num} apple", "{num} apples", num).format(num=num)
my_single_string = gettext("this is a text")
```

When using `ngettext` and `gettext` in the same file the generated `.po` file doesn't include the `msgid_plural` attribute for the first string

```
#: .\test_app\test_translation.py:10
msgid "{num} apple"
msgstr ""

#: .\test_app\test_translation.py:11
msgid "this is a text"
msgstr ""
```

I don't understand what is the problem in this code? Do I need to manually add the `msgid_plural` to each plural form of the strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alias `ngettext` as `_`. Only functions with single argument (gettext or gettext_lazy) can be aliased as `_` as stated in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation). The reason is how xgettext (GNU gettext tool) works.

Answer (score 0):

the weird part about this situation is if you change the imports like this

```
from django.utils.translation import ngettext
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

It will work as expected :)